# Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined at HTMLTableRowElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've looked around for a solution but I might just be missing something really obvious because they don't solve my issue. I am no JS wiz at all, just a disclaimer.

I have an ASP project where JavaScript calls some C# code some times. I start my code with this:

```
window.onload = function () {
    LiveSearch();
    getCredentials();
    getAllUsers();
    getIsAdmin();
};
```

All of these functions work just fine. But the one of interest is getAllUsers() because it contacts the backend via an AJAX call to get some data to fill in a table.

```
function getAllUsers() {
    var result_body = "";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/Home/GetAllUsers',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(""),
        success: function (users) {
            PushToScope("users", users);
            var dict = scope[2];
            if (dict.key.length > 0) {
                for (var key in dict.value) {
                    result_body += '<tr onclick="getClickedUserObject(' + dict["value"][key].Initials + ')\">';
                    result_body += '<td class=\"col-xs-4\">' + dict["value"][key].Name + '</td>'
                    result_body += '<td class=\"col-xs-4\">' + dict["value"][key].Title + '</td>'
                    result_body += '<td class=\"col-xs-4\">' + dict["value"][key].Department + '</td>'
                    result_body += '<td style=\"display: none\">' + dict["value"][key].PrivatePhone + '</td>'
                    result_body += '<td style=\"display: none\">' + dict["value"][key].WorkEmail + '</td>'
                    result_body += '<td style=\"display: none\">' + dict["value"][key].WorkPhoneLandline + '</td>'
                    result_body += '<td style=\"display: none\">' + dict["value"][key].WorkPhoneMobile + '</td>'
                    result_body += '</tr>';
                }
            } else {
                result_body += '<tr>';
                result_body += '<td style=\"col-xs-12\"><b>No Data. Try again, or Contact IT Support.</b></td>';
                result_body += '</tr>';
            }
            $('#result-table').html(result_body);
        }
    });
}
```

Like I said, the above works, but the problem comes forth when I click an element in my table. "getClickedUserObject()" below:

```
function getClickedUserObject(lettercode) {
    if (lettercode != undefined) {
        var users = scope[2];
        var user = users["value"][lettercode];
        $('#result-title').html(user.Title);
        $('#result-name').html(user.Name);
        $('#result-department').html(user.Department);
        $('#result-email').html('<a href=\"mailto:' + user.WorkEmail + '\">' + work.WorkEmail + '</a>');
        $('#result-work-mobile').html(user.WorkPhoneMobile);
        $('#result-work-landline').html(user.WorkPhoneLandline);
        $('#result-private-mobile').html(user.PrivatePhone);
        if (lettercode == scope[0]) {
            $("#HidePrivate").show();
            $("#HidePrivate").disabled = false;
            $("#HidePrivate").checked = user.HiddenPrivatePhone;
        } else {
            $("#HidePrivate").hide();
            $("#HidePrivate").disabled = true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This function never fires, instead I get the error in the title, saying that whatever lettercode I would get from clicking a row is not defined. This is odd to me because looking in the Google Chrome inspector I see this:

[image]

So what gives?

Comment: You try to access an attribute of an object that doesn't exist, without working example I can't relly help much, it's probably one of the `users.*`, you could comment out the whole block and then line by line remove comments to see at which point it break

Comment: M.D pointed out the issue already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with your function, but maybe the argument should be a string? Looks like you don't have any quotes around it in the function call.

Like so:

```
result_body += '<tr onclick=\"getClickedUserObject(\'' + dict["value"][key].Initials + '\')\">';
```

Comment: Yeah that was the problem. Not sure what you are getting down-voted for. Thanks!